# Notification with pending intent won't make phone call

Tags: java, android

I have a notification with a pending intent and once clicked it is supposed to dial a number. The notification comes up but once clicked nothing happens. I have set permission for the app to make calls in the android manifest file as follows:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Below is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
    addListenerOnRatingBar();

    NotificationCompat.Builder myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Calling 021-12345678")
            .setContentTitle("Phone Call Notification");

    Intent phoneCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    phoneCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:021-12345678"));
    PendingIntent phoneCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, phoneCall, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    myNotification.setContentIntent(phoneCallIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, myNotification.build());

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is actually workd (LOL).
But since you are using a pending intent, it needs a triger to launch (Click on the notification and it will call ;-).
Try to replace to a simple intent.
Like this: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);`

And it will work like a charm.

P.S. I'm don't really understand why are using a notification, since when you call someone the call is taking control over the screen.

Comment: I am clicking on the notification but it won't call. I tried changing it to ACTION_DIAL and that works perfectly, even passing the number over to the dialler but I need it to call straight away, hence why I am using ACTION_CALL

Comment: @Haldamir Well, IDK, I have tried your code and it worked, Anyway, try to send a simple intent, these two lines above, if it's doen't work, maybe there is another problem...